# Storing the state of a ToggleSwitch Into A Variable in C# and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

**EDIT :** It's been solved. I slept on it and Bradley's comment helped me a ton! Thanks!

So I have a series of ToggleSwitches.  Here's hows things are setup:

```
<ToggleSwitch
        x:Name="PrimaryToggle"
        Header="Primary"
        Toggled="PrimaryToggle_Toggled"/>

<ToggleSwitch
        x:Name="SecondaryToggle"
        Header="Secondary"
        Toggled="SecondaryToggle_Toggled"/>

<ToggleSwitch x:Name="Child1Toggle" Header="Child 1" />
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="Child2Toggle" Header="Child 2" />
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="Child3Toggle" Header="Child 3" />
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="Child4Toggle" Header="Child 4" />
```

In the code behind I have things setup like this:

```
// Parent Toggle (resets everything)
private void PrimaryToggle_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (PrimaryToggle.IsOn == true)
    {
        Child1Toggle.IsOn = false;
        Child2Toggle.IsOn = true;
        Child3Toggle.IsOn = false;
        Child4Toggle.IsOn = true;

    }
    else if (PrimaryToggle.IsOn == false)
    {
        this.allToggles(false);
    }
}

/* This is where I need to store the current state of the child toggles
   so when it turns off it will restore the saved state of them */
private void SecondaryToggle_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (SecondaryToggle.IsOn == true)
    {
        /* Need to store current state of children toggles
           In this section here: */
        Child1Toggle.IsOn = true;
        Child2Toggle.IsOn = true;
        Child3Toggle.IsOn = false;
        Child4Toggle.IsOn = false;
    }

if (SecondaryToggle.IsOn == false && PrimaryToggle.IsOn == true)
    {
        /* Need to restore previous state of children 
       toggles in this section here: */
    }
}
```

So the problem is I'm pretty new to C# so I'm trying to track down the best way to handle this.  Based on previous research I've come to the conclusion that I may need to use INotifyPropertyChanged and then set bindings on all the toggles I need to save, but I really do not know where to begin with that.  I've done some { get; set; } stuff a while back but haven't used it in a while so I'm pretty much having a brainfart.

Any advice on where to begin?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you are asking for, but it sounds like you just need to declare a Boolean variable for each toggle to save the state.  You can declare it at the class level, and just set it to the `.IsOn` property of the toggle to save it, and then set `IsOn` to the value of the variable to reload it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained it a bit better.  Essentially once I toggle the PrimaryToggle it will set a few children toggles to specific values.  After that, I can mess around with the child toggles to change some visual options. But then I have the secondarytoggle that will change all the toggles again, but I want the childrentoggles to return to the state they were before toggling the secondarytoggle IF the secondarytoggle is set to IsOn == false;

Comment: and I apologize for my lack of knowledge of C# :(  I'm learning at the moment.  Primarily doing XAML at the moment.

Comment: Okay, I slept on it and your comment made perfect sense this morning. Thanks @BradleyUffner! That helped me solve it

Comment: please **please** post more details in an answer below instead of simply writing "it has been solved". I doubt others with similar issues accepts your "sleep on it" solution

Comment: [XKCD - Wisdom of the Ancients](https://xkcd.com/979)

Comment: I had to get through work before I could, but wanted to let people know earlier that there is a solution.  Adding the solution as an answer right now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this solution isn't the most elegant, but it DOES work, so here we go.

You need to declare some bools in the class that can store the state of your ToggleSwitches:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public bool child1var { get; set; }
    public bool child2var { get; set; }
    public bool child3var { get; set; }
    public bool child4var { get; set; }
```

after you've set those, you'll need to set their data below

```
private void SecondaryToggle_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (SecondaryToggle.IsOn == true)
    {
        // Here we save the state of the Child toggles 
        // before setting them to a different setting
        child1var = Child1Toggle.IsOn;
        child2var = Child2Toggle.IsOn;
        child3var = Child3Toggle.IsOn;
        child4var = Child4Toggle.IsOn;

        Child1Toggle.IsOn = true;
        Child2Toggle.IsOn = true;
        Child3Toggle.IsOn = false;
        Child4Toggle.IsOn = false;
    }
```

Finally when we turn off the Secondary toggle, we set it back to what it was:

```
if (SecondaryToggle.IsOn == false && PrimaryToggle.IsOn == true)
    {
        Child1Toggle.IsOn = child1var;
        Child2Toggle.IsOn = child2var;
        Child3Toggle.IsOn = child3var;
        Child4Toggle.IsOn = child4var;
    }
}
```

This sets the data back to what it was before.

Hope this helps someone else!  Again, I know this probably isn't the best solution, and there's probably a good way of sorting a lot of this stuff into other classes and such and if I learn those soon, I'll be sure to update this post with that information!